# EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel is executed twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to open an OBJ file in Unity using C# during runtime when I press L. However, the file dialog always opens twice. After I selected the first file, I get a new dialog. Whatever file I select the first and second time, both files are opened and displayed.
I have:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L)) {
        LoadObj();
        //StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime(5));
    }
}
IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
}
void LoadObj()
{
    string path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Load scan file", "", "obj");
    \\Open the file and display it
}
```

I tried:

- Add a time (see commented code above) -- did not work
- Add a boolean that allows to execute `LoadObj()` only when the previous file is opened -- did not work
- Added `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel()` before or after `yield return new WaitForSeconds(time)` -- in the latter case, there is the delay of 5 seconds, but it still opens twice in both cases.

I searched for other solutions, but did not find anything else.
I work on a Windows machine and use Unity 2018. The aim is to open a single file at a time, but it must be possible to open another file, say, after a few minutes.
Any idea how to prevent the dialog from opening twice?

Comment: Can you try a few things? 1) Try calling the `LoadObj()` inside the `ExecuteAfterTime` coroutine after the line of `WaitForSeconds` instead of directly calling it in Update.   2) Add some Debug logs before the `OpenFilePanel` and also before the actual display file logic. And see how many logs are being printed.

Comment: Are you sure you set the script only on one game object?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is unfortunately not working, as I added to my original question. When I place a `Debug.Log()` before and after the `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel()` command, I first get the first file dialog, immediately after I selected a file, I get the second and only after I selected both files, the four debug lines are output.

Answer (score 0):

As @Eshan Mohammadi suggested, I checked if I only had a single instance of the code. I deleted the entire file, created a new one and added it to my GameObject. However, only then I noticed that this particular GameObject is copied, including the code, of course.
So, I chaned the way the GameObject was copied and problem solved.

Comment: You may have soled your issue but note that `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel` can only be used in the Editor. You cannot build your project with that. It will not work in a build.